# Insert a Form value from a select in a dynamic url

Tags: laravel

While using laravel to create a movie catalog, I am trying to extract the value from an HTML Form and insert it in the URL.

The objective is that, from the main page which is:
http://127.0.0.1:8000/index/

I want it to extract an ID value from the form and insert it in the url:

http://127.0.0.1:8000/index/1

http://127.0.0.1:8000/index/2

http://127.0.0.1:8000/index/3

As each one is a dynamic view that will display each movie information from the database.
The form is already recognizing the ids and is displaying them in the select form in page, but I am not able to have that value used to insert it in the url as shown above.

Please help me, here is my code:

**index.blade.php**

```
                <form action=" WHAT TO PLACE HERE??? " method="POST">
                    @csrf

                    <select name="selector">
                        <option value="" disabled selected> --- ID --- </option>
                        @foreach($movies as $movie)
                        <option value="{{ $movie->id }}">{{ $movie->id }}</option>
                        @endforeach

                    </select>

                    <button>Buscar</button>
                </form>
```

**web.php**

```
Route::get('/index', 'App\Http\Controllers\MovieController@index');
Route::get('/index/create','App\Http\Controllers\MovieController@create'); 
Route::post('/index','App\Http\Controllers\MovieController@store'); 
Route::get('/index/{id}','App\Http\Controllers\MovieController@show');
Route::delete('/index/{id}','App\Http\Controllers\MovieController@destroy');
```

**MovieController.php**

```
class MovieController extends Controller
{
    public function index() {
        $movies = Movie::all();    
        return view('movies.index', ['movies' => $movies,]);
    }

    public function show($id) {
        $movie = Movie::findOrFail($id); 
        return view('movies.show', ['movie' => $movie]);
        }


    public function create() {
    return view('movies.create');
    }

    public function store(){
    
        $movie = new Movie(); 

        $movie->title = request('title'); 
        $movie->synopsis = request('synopsis'); 
        $movie->year = request('year'); 
        $movie->cover = request('cover');      

        $movie->save();    

        return redirect('/')->with('mssg','La película a sido registrada'); 
    }

    public function destroy($id) {
        $movie = Movie::findOrFail($id);
        $movie->delete(); 

        return redirect('/index/'); 
    }

}
```

Comment: @a-id What is the objective to add the id into the url on change of select value? Means, Do you want to redirect to the selected movie ?

Comment: yes, I have a dynamic view call "show" that when adding the main url with each movie id, it creates a dynamic view that displays the selected id movie information. That part works, like, if I add the id manually on the url, it displays the movie, however, I want to do that through the select in the html form.

Comment: @a-id you can use the list-view of the html to fulfill your requirement, Is it necessary to use the form ?!

Answer (score 0):

Replace you form as:

**index.blade.php**

```
 <form action="" method="POST" id="form_id">
    @csrf
        <select name="selector" id="selector">
          <option value="" disabled selected> --- ID --- </option>
          @foreach($movies as $movie)
            <option value="{{ $movie->id }}">{{ $movie->id }}</option>
          @endforeach
       </select>
    <button type="submit">Buscar</button>
 </form>
```

**Add script after this :**

```
<script>
$('#selector').change(function(){
    var selected_value = $(this).val();
   $('#form_id').attr('action', 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/'+selected_value);
});
</script>
```

This will set your action dynamic as per selection with your select tag

Comment: Thanks for the help and your time, unfortunately, it did not work, seems that Laravel is getting in the way with an error message: "SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'title' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `movies` (`title`, `synopsis`, `year`, `cover`) values (?, ?, ?, ?))".

Comment: Please first check your parameters name as in **store** method you are inserting `title, synopsis, year, cover`  and in **blade** you are passing `selector`, then it will never work. You must use the param which you to save else make that fields **nullable** or pass it with **hidden** values.